# C++ Простейший калькулятор

Tags: c++

Привет всем!

Решил я изучать *С++*, но тут проблема. Написал я калькулятор, а он не работает. В результате действий пишет "0".

Вот код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <conio.h>
float a, b, c;
char d;
int p;
int main()
{

    while (p != 2)
    {
        printf("1 = calculator \n 2 - exit \n");
        scanf("%d", &p);
        switch (p)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            float c;
            printf("First number ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("Action with numbers ");
            scanf("%s", &d);
            printf("Second number ");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            if (d == '+')
                c = a + b;
            if (d == '-')
                c = a - b;
            if (d == '*')
                c = a * b;
            if (d == '/')
                c = a / b;
            system("cls");
        }
        case 2:
        {
            break;
        }
        }
        printf("Result = %2.f \n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Отформатируйте код. 2. Ошибка в несоответствии строки формата функции scanf и типов переменных.

Comment: Решили изучить C++, но пишите при этом на C. Пары плюсовых инклюдов для этого маловато.

Answer (score 4):

Вы читаете `d` как строку, в то время как это `char`. Для него надо использовать спецификатор `%c`. Далее, не `%d` для `float`, а `%f`. И почему бы вам не пользоваться `double` - чай, на дворе не 80-е годы... :)

Ну и я бы вместо лесенки `if`'ов использовал `switch`.

```
case 2: break
```

Вас выбросит из `switch`, но не из `while`. Опять же, при входе в `while` значение `p` не определено...

Я бы делал что-то такое - правда, тут защиты от дурака (неверного ввода) никакой, но это уже самостоятельно :)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    char d;
    int p = 1;
    while (p != 2)
    {
        printf("1 - calculator\n2 - exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &p);
        if (p != 1) break;
        printf("Write expression (without spaces): ");
        scanf("%lf%c%lf", &a,&d,&b);
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        switch(d)
        {
        case '+': c = a + b; break;
        case '-': c = a - b; break;
        case '*': c = a * b; break;
        case '/': c = a / b; break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong action\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Result = %lf\n", c);
    }
}
```

Просто вводите типа `2*2` и все.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы учите **С++**, вместо `printf` и `scanf` лучше использовать `cout` и `cin`. В них не нужно заботиться о формате принимаемого и выводимого значений, плюс нету такой проблемы, как попадание в буфер ввода не того символа. В вашем случае вместо `%d` для считывания значений типа `float` нужно использовать `%f`, а для считывания символа `%c`. Во время работы вашего кода после поправки форматирования у меня, например, вместо считывания символа операции считывался знак новой строки, и ввод переходил сразу на второе число. Для избежания этого следовало бы очистить буфер ввода командой `fflush(stdin)`. Однако все эти вопросы решаются использованием `cout` и `cin`.

Далее, у вас дважды объявлена переменная `c`, одна - глобальная, а вторая - в области видимости `case 1:`. Внутри `case 1:` вы присваиваете результат локальной переменной, а команда вывода результата на экран находится вне области видимости этой переменной, и выводит на экран глобальную переменную `c`, которой ничего присвоено не было, отсюда и постоянный результат `0`.

Вот моя версия кода:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float a, b, c;
char d;
int p;
int main()
{

    while (p != 2)
    {
        cout << "1 = calculator \n 2 - exit \n";
        cin >> p;
        switch (p)
        {
        case 1:
        {
           cout <<"First number ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "Action with numbers ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Second number ";
            cin >> b;
            if (d == '+')
                c = a + b;
            if (d == '-')
                c = a - b;
            if (d == '*')
                c = a * b;
            if (d == '/')
                c = a / b;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            break;
        }
        }
        cout << "Result =" << c <<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

данный калькулятор с защитой от деления на нуль:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float a, b, c;
char d;
int p;
int main()
{

    while (p != 2)
    {
        cout << "1 = calculator \n 2 - exit \n";
        cin >> p;
        switch (p)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "First number >> ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "Action with numbers >> ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Second number >> ";
            cin >> b;
            if (d == '+')
            {
                c = a + b;
                cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
            }
            if (d == '-')
            {
                c = a - b;
                cout << a << " - " << b << " = " << c << endl;
            }
            if (d == '*')
            {
                c = a * b;
                cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << c << endl;
            }
            if (d == '/')
            {
                c = a / b;
                cout << a << " / " << b << " = " << c << endl;
                try
                {
                    if (b == 0)
                        throw 123;
                }
                catch (int q)
                {
                    cout << " Error number " << q << " >> divide by 0!" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        case 2:
        {
            break;
        }
        }
        cout << "Result = " << c << endl;
    }
}
```